# Is there a conventional term for this parametrization?

Tags: functions, parametrization, convention

Given a function $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$, and scalars $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$, is there a conventional term for giving it the following parameters?

$$g(x;a,b,c,d) \triangleq af(bx+c)+d$$

Comment: What does $f(x;a,b,c,d)$ mean, the expression on the right? If so, best not to use f. Not sure what your question is then, you can call the right hand side anything you like.

Comment: If $f_1(x) = ax+b$ and $f_2(x) = bx+c$ then the right hand side is $f_1(f(f_2(x)))$ or the composition $f_1ofof_2(x)$. Which probably doesn't help much.

Comment: @Paul I agree with you that these compositions produce the desired form.